# RabbitMq server Boot up failed

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to boot the rabbitMq server on my linux machine, but it is failing to start and giving below issue in logs.

Starting RabbitMQ 3.8.9 on Erlang 23.1

```
2021-11-23 04:37:54.238 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
2021-11-23 04:37:54.238 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
2021-11-23 04:37:54.238 [error] <0.271.0> 
2021-11-23 04:37:54.238 [error] <0.271.0> BOOT FAILED
2021-11-23 04:37:54.239 [error] <0.271.0> ===========
2021-11-23 04:37:54.239 [error] <0.271.0> Exception during startup:
2021-11-23 04:37:54.239 [error] <0.271.0> 
2021-11-23 04:37:54.239 [error] <0.271.0>     rabbit_boot_steps:run_boot_steps/1 line 20
2021-11-23 04:37:54.239 [error] <0.271.0>     rabbit_boot_steps:'-run_boot_steps/1-lc$^0/1-0-'/1 line 19
2021-11-23 04:37:54.239 [error] <0.271.0>     rabbit_boot_steps:run_step/2 line 46
2021-11-23 04:37:54.239 [error] <0.271.0>     rabbit_boot_steps:'-run_step/2-lc$^0/1-0-'/2 line 41
2021-11-23 04:37:54.239 [error] <0.271.0>     rabbit:insert_default_data/0 line 1018
2021-11-23 04:37:54.240 [error] <0.271.0>     rabbit_auth_backend_internal:add_user_sans_validation/3 line 211
2021-11-23 04:37:54.240 [error] <0.271.0>     rabbit_password:hash/2 line 25
2021-11-23 04:37:54.240 [error] <0.271.0>     crypto:notsup_to_error/1 line 2635
2021-11-23 04:37:54.240 [error] <0.271.0> error:notsup
2021-11-23 04:37:54.240 [error] <0.271.0> 
2021-11-23 04:37:55.240 [info] <0.632.0> Closing all connections in vhost '/' on node 'rabbit@ip-10-210-16-182' because the vhost is stopping
2021-11-23 04:37:55.240 [info] <0.270.0> [{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.270.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{notsup,{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,138}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,226}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.269.0>]},{message_queue_len,1},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.271.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.269.0>,<0.44.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,1598},{stack_size,28},{reductions,405}], []
2021-11-23 04:37:55.240 [info] <0.656.0> Stopping message store for directory '/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ip-10-210-16-182/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_persistent'
2021-11-23 04:37:55.240 [error] <0.270.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.270.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {notsup,{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}} in application_master:init/4 line 138
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try a higher version of `RabbitMq` that also supports `Erlang 23` but might be updated to deal with the compatibility issues.

[image]

If you follow the `Erlang 23` compatibility update page, you will see they had a few issues with `Erlang 23` and `RabbitMq` initially.

Compatibility Discussions: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/wlPIWz3UYHQ

https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html

---

According to the discussion page, you could also update your debian packages to ensure everything is up to date. <-- See last post on the page